# TinyOS Mote to PC Communication Error in HplAtm128UartC

Tags: tinyos, nesc

Good Morning,
I'm trying to use TinyOS for a WSN.
I'm using the app folder where there are:
- BaseStation
- BaseStation 15.4
- test/TestSerial

but for all app when i do "make iris" it generate the error:

> In component `HplAtm128UartC':
>   ../../tos/chips/atm128/HplAtm128UartC.nc:59: cannot find`HplUart0Config'
>   ../../tos/chips/atm128/HplAtm128UartC.nc:64: cannot find `HplUart1Config'
>   make: *** [exe] Error 1

How can I fix that?

Comment: What TinyOS distribution do you use? In the official version from the repository there's no HplUart0Config nor HplUart1Config in the component HplAtm128UartC:
https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main/blob/master/tos/chips/atm128/HplAtm128UartC.nc

Comment: I use the last TinyOS versione 2.1.2

Comment: Now i try to simulate code using RadioCountToLeds and TOSSIM and the reference manual but it give me the Segmentation Fault error. How can I solve it?

Comment: I simulate another test code: RadioCountToLed in apps folder using the TinyOS wiki and it give me the same error. The error argument of this question exist only if i take command: "make iris" but not for "make micaz"

Comment: micaz is the only platform supported by TOSSIM:
http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/TOSSIM#Compiling_TOSSIM

Comment: No, you're not using TinyOS 2.1.2, at least not this one:
https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main/releases/tag/release_tinyos_2_1_2
As I wrote before, HplAtm128UartC doesn't refer to HplUart0Config nor HplUart1Config in the linked version as well.

Comment: How i say which version i use? 
My OS is ubuntu, i use this guide to install: http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/Installing_From_Source.
Can I substitute my version with the 2.1.2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolve it by reinstall all of component.
But when I try to use this tutorial: [Mote-PC tutorial](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/Mote-PC_serial_communication_and_SerialForwarder_%28TOS_2.1.1_and_later%29) I have this problem:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestSerialMsg

or the same error when I apply on the BlinkToRadio:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BlinkToRadioMsg

How can i Solve this?

Comment: Please do not post an answer which isn't an answer, but another question. Consider asking a new question instead.